# Сохранение фильтра поиска для Ajax

Tags: php

Имеется форма поиска с блоком результатов с ограничением вывода по 5 на страницу (pagination).
Вопрос в том, что можно придумать, чтобы сохранить ранее выбранный фильтр-поиска при переходе по пагинации?

Comment: cookie, Local Storage

Comment: Либо сохранение фильтра в сессии

Comment: или location.hash, как тут http://sweetness.com.ua/uhod-za-licom/

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть минимум 2 варианта, если используется ajax:

1. Сохранить в js-переменную и передавать значение фильтра как параметр к следующему ajax-запросу.
2. Сохранить фильтр как атрибут в какой-нибудь невидимый элемент верстки.

Пояснения:

```
filter = 'search_string=aaa&page=2';
...
var url = '/search.php?' + filter;
```

или

```
$('#hidden_element').attr('filter', 'search_string=aaa&page=2');
...
var url = '/search.php?' + $('#filter').attr('filter');
```

Comment: хорошая практика  - делать поиск так, чтобы были видны параметры запроса в адресной строке. Чтобы ссылку другу кинуть или себе сохранить и тд